# Вывод xml разметки на странице

Tags: php, html, xml

есть php файл

```
<?php

echo <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
  <link>https://www.w3schools.com</link>
  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>XML Tutorial</title>
    <link>https://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>
    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>

END;

?>
```

при переходе на сайт вижу

```
https://www.w3schools.com Free web building tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp New RSS tutorial on W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/xml New XML tutorial on W3Schools
```

как отображать именно разметку так как она написана а не содержимое тегов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клиент не в курсе какой тип данных вы хотите ему предоставить, и по умолчанию пытается отобразить его как `html`.

Добавляйте следующую строку перед `echo`

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```